# ¿Por que la etiqueta hr no se coloca debajo de cada div que le indico? desde jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal, diálogo

A partir de un **array** que obtengo de la **db**, creo un modal con [***bootstrap3-dialog***](https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog).

Creo los elementos fácilmente, con el único que tengo inconvenientes es con la etiqueta **hr**, ya que no se colocan debajo de cada elemento que indico, sino que todos se muestran agrupados en la parte **superior-derecha** del **modal**.

[image]

A continuación, lo que intento:

```js
let valores = [{"id":7,"n_activo":"0811049","nombre":"Ciller 1-1","mar_mod":"Trane / CGAFC304AHA10000E0000000000000","serial":"C03M11007","ldp":"Servicios Criticos","estatus":0},{"id":9,"n_activo":"0811050","nombre":"Chiller 1-2","mar_mod":"Trane / CGAFC304AHA10000E0000000000000","serial":"C03M11008","ldp":"Servicios Criticos","estatus":0},{"id":20,"n_activo":"0811058","nombre":"Bomba B Chiller 1-1","mar_mod":"Armstrong / 3x2x10    4030","serial":"490976","ldp":"Servicios Criticos","estatus":0},{"id":19,"n_activo":"0811143","nombre":"Compresor","mar_mod":"Bottarini / Ks 45 - ESE 30","serial":"BA23011002","ldp":"Servicios Criticos","estatus":0}];

BootstrapDialog.show({
  title: 'Equipos en Buen Estado',
  type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_SUCCESS,
  message: function(dialogRef) {
    dialogRef.getModalContent()[0].getElementsByClassName("modal-body")[0].setAttribute('class', 'panel-body');

    let form = $('<form/>',{
      'id' : 'form_eliminar_item',
      'role'  : 'form',
      'class'  : 'form-horizontal'
    });

    for(n in valores){
      div = $('<div/>',{
        'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
      });
        label = $('<label/>',{
          'class' : 'control-label col-sm-3 col-xs-12',
          'text'    : '#: '
        });
        label.appendTo(div);
        div_field = $('<div/>',{
          'class' : 'col-sm-9 col-xs-12',
        });
          field = $('<span/>',{
            'class' : 'col-sm-10',
            'text'    : (parseInt(n)+1)
          });
          field.appendTo(div_field);
        div_field.appendTo(div);
      div.appendTo(form);

      div = $('<div/>',{
        'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
      });
        label = $('<label/>',{
          'class' : 'control-label col-sm-3 col-xs-12',
          'text'    : 'Área: '
        });
        label.appendTo(div);
        div_field = $('<div/>',{
          'class' : 'col-sm-9 col-xs-12',
        });
          field = $('<span/>',{
            'class' : 'col-sm-10',
            'text'    : valores[n].ldp
          });
          field.appendTo(div_field);
        div_field.appendTo(div);
      div.appendTo(form);

      div = $('<div/>',{
        'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
      });
        label = $('<label/>',{
          'class' : 'control-label col-sm-3 col-xs-12',
          'text'    : 'N° de Activo: '
        });
        label.appendTo(div);
        div_field = $('<div/>',{
          'class' : 'col-sm-9 col-xs-12',
        });
          field = $('<span/>',{
            'class' : 'col-sm-10',
            'text'    : valores[n].n_activo
          });
          field.appendTo(div_field);
        div_field.appendTo(div);
      div.appendTo(form);

      div = $('<div/>',{
        'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
      });
        label = $('<label/>',{
          'class' : 'control-label col-sm-3 col-xs-12',
          'text'    : 'Nombre: '
        });
        label.appendTo(div);
        div_field = $('<div/>',{
          'class' : 'col-sm-9 col-xs-12',
        });
          field = $('<span/>',{
            'class' : 'col-sm-10',
            'text'    : valores[n].nombre
          });
          field.appendTo(div_field);
        div_field.appendTo(div);
      div.appendTo(form);

      div = $('<div/>',{
        'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
      });
        label = $('<label/>',{
          'class' : 'control-label col-sm-3 col-xs-12',
          'text'    : 'Serial: '
        });
        label.appendTo(div);
        div_field = $('<div/>',{
          'class' : 'col-sm-9 col-xs-12',
        });
          field = $('<span/>',{
            'class' : 'col-sm-10',
            'text'    : valores[n].serial
          });
          field.appendTo(div_field);
        div_field.appendTo(div);
      div.appendTo(form);

      div = $('<div/>',{
        'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
      });
        label = $('<label/>',{
          'class' : 'control-label col-sm-3 col-xs-12',
          'text'    : 'Marca / Modelo: '
        });
        label.appendTo(div);
        div_field = $('<div/>',{
          'class' : 'col-sm-9 col-xs-12',
        });
          field = $('<span/>',{
            'class' : 'col-sm-10',
            'text'    : valores[n].mar_mod
          });
          field.appendTo(div_field);
        div_field.appendTo(div);
      div.appendTo(form);
      
      if(parseInt(n) < (valores.length - 1)){
        div = $('<hr/>',{
          'style' : 'display: block; margin-top: 0.5em; margin-bottom: 0.5em; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border-style: inset; border-width: 1px;',
        });
        div.appendTo(form);
      }
    }
    return form;
  },
  buttons: [
    {
      label: 'Ver en los registros',
      action: function(dialog) {
        
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.4/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.4/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los elementos `<hr>` no se muestran correctamente por que no tienen asignada una clase correcta de bootstrap por lo que aparecen flotando dentro del formulario.

Deberías envolverlos en un div con una clase apropiada, por ejemplo podría queda de la siguiente manera en html:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <hr style="display: block; margin-top: 0.5em; margin-bottom: 0.5em; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border-style: inset; border-width: 1px;">
</div>
```

Para conseguir esto deberias modificar la parte del script que genera la etiqueta `hr` de la siguiente manera:

```
  if(parseInt(n) < (valores.length - 1)){
    div = $('<div/>',{
      'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
    });
    hr = $('<hr/>',{
      'style' : 'display: block; margin-top: 0.5em; margin-bottom: 0.5em; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border-style: inset; border-width: 1px;',
    });
    hr.appendTo(div);
    div.appendTo(form);
  }
```

```js
let valores = [{"id":7,"n_activo":"0811049","nombre":"Ciller 1-1","mar_mod":"Trane / CGAFC304AHA10000E0000000000000","serial":"C03M11007","ldp":"Servicios Criticos","estatus":0},{"id":9,"n_activo":"0811050","nombre":"Chiller 1-2","mar_mod":"Trane / CGAFC304AHA10000E0000000000000","serial":"C03M11008","ldp":"Servicios Criticos","estatus":0},{"id":20,"n_activo":"0811058","nombre":"Bomba B Chiller 1-1","mar_mod":"Armstrong / 3x2x10    4030","serial":"490976","ldp":"Servicios Criticos","estatus":0},{"id":19,"n_activo":"0811143","nombre":"Compresor","mar_mod":"Bottarini / Ks 45 - ESE 30","serial":"BA23011002","ldp":"Servicios Criticos","estatus":0}];

BootstrapDialog.show({
  title: 'Equipos en Buen Estado',
  type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_SUCCESS,
  message: function(dialogRef) {
    dialogRef.getModalContent()[0].getElementsByClassName("modal-body")[0].setAttribute('class', 'panel-body');

    let form = $('<form/>',{
      'id' : 'form_eliminar_item',
      'role'  : 'form',
      'class'  : 'form-horizontal'
    });

    for(n in valores){
      div = $('<div/>',{
        'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
      });
        label = $('<label/>',{
          'class' : 'control-label col-sm-3 col-xs-12',
          'text'    : '#: '
        });
        label.appendTo(div);
        div_field = $('<div/>',{
          'class' : 'col-sm-9 col-xs-12',
        });
          field = $('<span/>',{
            'class' : 'col-sm-10',
            'text'    : (parseInt(n)+1)
          });
          field.appendTo(div_field);
        div_field.appendTo(div);
      div.appendTo(form);

      div = $('<div/>',{
        'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
      });
        label = $('<label/>',{
          'class' : 'control-label col-sm-3 col-xs-12',
          'text'    : 'Área: '
        });
        label.appendTo(div);
        div_field = $('<div/>',{
          'class' : 'col-sm-9 col-xs-12',
        });
          field = $('<span/>',{
            'class' : 'col-sm-10',
            'text'    : valores[n].ldp
          });
          field.appendTo(div_field);
        div_field.appendTo(div);
      div.appendTo(form);

      div = $('<div/>',{
        'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
      });
        label = $('<label/>',{
          'class' : 'control-label col-sm-3 col-xs-12',
          'text'    : 'N° de Activo: '
        });
        label.appendTo(div);
        div_field = $('<div/>',{
          'class' : 'col-sm-9 col-xs-12',
        });
          field = $('<span/>',{
            'class' : 'col-sm-10',
            'text'    : valores[n].n_activo
          });
          field.appendTo(div_field);
        div_field.appendTo(div);
      div.appendTo(form);

      div = $('<div/>',{
        'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
      });
        label = $('<label/>',{
          'class' : 'control-label col-sm-3 col-xs-12',
          'text'    : 'Nombre: '
        });
        label.appendTo(div);
        div_field = $('<div/>',{
          'class' : 'col-sm-9 col-xs-12',
        });
          field = $('<span/>',{
            'class' : 'col-sm-10',
            'text'    : valores[n].nombre
          });
          field.appendTo(div_field);
        div_field.appendTo(div);
      div.appendTo(form);

      div = $('<div/>',{
        'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
      });
        label = $('<label/>',{
          'class' : 'control-label col-sm-3 col-xs-12',
          'text'    : 'Serial: '
        });
        label.appendTo(div);
        div_field = $('<div/>',{
          'class' : 'col-sm-9 col-xs-12',
        });
          field = $('<span/>',{
            'class' : 'col-sm-10',
            'text'    : valores[n].serial
          });
          field.appendTo(div_field);
        div_field.appendTo(div);
      div.appendTo(form);

      div = $('<div/>',{
        'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
      });
        label = $('<label/>',{
          'class' : 'control-label col-sm-3 col-xs-12',
          'text'    : 'Marca / Modelo: '
        });
        label.appendTo(div);
        div_field = $('<div/>',{
          'class' : 'col-sm-9 col-xs-12',
        });
          field = $('<span/>',{
            'class' : 'col-sm-10',
            'text'    : valores[n].mar_mod
          });
          field.appendTo(div_field);
        div_field.appendTo(div);
      div.appendTo(form);
      
      if(parseInt(n) < (valores.length - 1)){
        div = $('<div/>',{
          'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
        });
        hr = $('<hr/>',{
          'style' : 'display: block; margin-top: 0.5em; margin-bottom: 0.5em; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border-style: inset; border-width: 1px;',
        });
        hr.appendTo(div);
        div.appendTo(form);
      }
    }
    return form;
  },
  buttons: [
    {
      label: 'Ver en los registros',
      action: function(dialog) {
        
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.4/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.4/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gracias hermano, creí que no requerían de la clase de un **div** para ello.